# text editor CKE showing html tags in browser

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, text-editor

I'm using laravel 9 in blade file I mentioned cke text editor but its showing html tags in page only while update.

**below is code how its defined**

```
src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/35.1.0/classic/ckeditor.js"


<textarea type="text" class="form-control" name="description" id="editor" >{{ old('description'}}</textarea>
```

**below is the script**

````
  ClassicEditor
        .create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ) )
        .then( editor => {
            console.log( editor );
        } )
        .catch( error => {
            console.error( error );
        } ); ```

I'm looking forward to your suggestions.
````

Comment: The content is escaped when you use `{{ old('description') }}` use `{!! old('description') !!}}` instead. Also, the saved description should be the second parameter for your `old()` function

Answer (score 0):

just change `{{ old('description'}}` to `{!! old('description') !!}`

Have a nice one. All the best.